# SQL Syntax help -- FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, T1 and T2.

T1 has fields id, Key_id, title. (id is the primary key, Key_id and title are obtained from T2.)

And

T2 has fields id, Key_id, title and F4. (id is obtained from T1 and Key_id is the primary key in T2)

Can you help in writing the syntax for the above using Foreign key and Primary key

Please comment if is not clear.

Comment: Consider using better names for your columns so they make sense.

Comment: You want someone to write the CREATE TABLE statements for you, or what? Is this homework?

Comment: Circular foreign key relationships between tables suggests to me that there's a problem with your data model. You might need a separate table to represent a relationship between T1 and T2. What's the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously can't create a foreign key constraint from T1 to T2 before T2 is defined, and vice versa. The trick is to create one table without the FK constraint, create the second table, and then use ALTER TABLE to add the FK constraint to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Keys have their own chapter in the nice MySQL Manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html